# Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedAttributeView.class) returns null on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, kotlin

I tried to set a user defined attribute on files in android. But I was unable to do it because of the null pointer exception on UserDefinedAttributeView object

I tried the following code to get details about the supported attributes on Android

```
    val supportedAttributes = FileSystems.getDefault().supportedFileAttributeViews()
    Log.e("+++UV", "$supportedAttributes")
```

I got the following output

```
 E/+++UV: [owner, dos, basic, posix, user, unix]
```

Then I tried the following code to read the user defined attributes

```
val userView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,  UserDefinedFileAttributeView::class.java)
Log.e("+++UV", "${userView.toString()}")
```

It gave me null pointer exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Does the app have access to the file at `path`?

Comment: yes, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions were given to the App